# Change color after click

Tags: jquery

After click on a button, only checked inputs should change their parent color on red (in this case "first"). When I click, nothing changed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function fun() {
      $('#duod').on('click', function() {
        $('.tu').filter(':checked').parent().css('color', 'red');
      })
    })();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="check">
    First <input class="tu" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div class="check">>First
    <input class="tu" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div class="check">
    First <input class="tu" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <button id="duod">button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your click logic is fine, the issue is because you've placed your code in an IIFE which runs immediately. This is *before* the DOM has loaded and no elements exist.

Instead you should place your code in a document.ready event handler, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#duod').on('click', function() {
        $('.tu').filter(':checked').parent().css('color', 'red');
      })
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="check">
    First <input class="tu" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div class="check">First
    <input class="tu" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div class="check">
    First <input class="tu" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <button id="duod">button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit : fixed html code in demo

Comment: edited the html the checkbox had one extra angular bracket

Answer (score 0):

Only need add "$" before function, example;

```
$(function fun() {
    $('#duod').on('click', function () {
    $('.tu').filter(':checked').parent().css('color', 'red');
    })
})();
```

Comment: Right answer - you dont need the `()` after the ready handler as well.